# TinyMCE editor is not loading because document is not in standards mode - how can I get my document in standards mode?

Tags: tinymce

I am so close to getting the TinyMCE editor to work at our site. The necessary scripts when adding a discussion are loading.I can see them in the HTML source. And my domain is properly registered for the API key I'm using. And the id/name of the textarea is correct. But the editor itself doesn't load for the textarea.

There is just one JavaScript console error:

*Failed to initialize the editor as the document is not in standards mode. TinyMCE requires standards mode.*

Does anybody know what "standards mode" is and how I can make sure the page served is in standards mode?

Comment: See https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-requires-standards-mode/ for more information about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A big never mind. I found the solution. The document was in so-called "quirks" mode because there was no DOCTYPE. I added this on top and the editor worked just fine!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: If it helps more information can be found on MDN about standards mode vs quirks mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Comment: For HTML 5, only `<!DOCTYPE html>` is required.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, It is necessary to use     `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Next is to make sure, If there is some output before  `<!DOCTYPE html>`, remove it.

It may cause error if something printed before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

Even later I discovered something that might help.

Check if the first tag is of the <!doctype html>.
In my case a  tag was taking the first place.